# Trigger Email if values in column change by x % (sending range of data)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Scripting and I need some help as I've been searching and tinkering to no avail.  What I have is a google sheet with 12 columns of data and a growing number of rows.  What I'd like to do is have an email sent to me if a value in one of those columns (column K) changes by more than 10% from it's previous value.  Furthermore, I'd like the email to contain the change in it with data from columns A:D (ie. This product has been changed by more than 10%), including a link to the sheet in question (will always be the same sheet).

I'm not sure if it's possible to have this log and perform an email update every hour (or custom) as opposed to right away.  If no changes, the email would say "no changes".

I know I'm asking for a lot but I'd really like some help, even if you tell me other examples that get me close to what I'm asking for.  Thanks in advance.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

White Google Sheets allows you to view the revision history for a Sheet, I do not see an API function to retrieve a past revision.  Therefore, I think you will need to design a solution that saves the values that you wish to compare against.  You could save these values to another Google Sheet, or you could save each value into a named script property.  The ultimate size of your spreadsheet would determine the best approach.

You will need to create a script function and cause it to be run from a timed trigger once per hour.  That script will grab a range of values

```
//Grab 10 rows from column K
var vals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 11, 10, 1);
```

To save these values (for the next execution).  In this example, the row number is being used as the key to the property object.  You might wish to use a value from another column instead.

```
 var docProp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
 for(var i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
   docProp.setProperty(i, vals[i][0]);
 }
```

To perform your comparison of new values to prior values, you will just need to compare the values in docProp before saving the value.

```
 var docProp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
 for(var i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
   var old = docProp.getProperty(i);
   //perform your comparison here.  Take action if value changes by more than 10%
   Logger.log("Old "+old+"; New "+vals[i][0]);
   docProp.setProperty(i, vals[i][0]);
 }
```